# Linq to Entities could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this as my model (modified for obvious reasons)

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
    public TypeDomainValue ModelType {get; set;}
}
```

ModelType is known in the database as a string value only (no tables connected).

However if I want to filter on the value of TypeDomainValue in a linq statement

```
models.Where(c => c.ModelType.Value.Contains(searchString));
```

I get the error that the Linq expression cannot be translated.
I already tried using EF.Functions.Like which creates a similar error.
How can I get this to be translated properly as I do not want to load the entire table into memory.

Edit:
I use the following ValueConverter

```
public class ModelTypeDomainValueConverter : ValueConverter<ModelTypeDomainValue, string>
{
    public ModelTypeDomainValueConverter([CanBeNull] ConverterMappingHints mappingHints = null) : base(ConvertToString(), ConvertToDomainValue(), mappingHints)
    {
    }

    private static Expression<Func<ModelTypeDomainValue, string>> ConvertToString()
    {
        return x => x.Value;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<string, ModelTypeDomainValue>> ConvertToDomainValue()
    {
        return x => ModelTypeDomainValue.CreateByValue(x);
    }
}
```

Which gets added with the following extension:

```
    public static ModelBuilder UseValueConverter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ValueConverter converter)
    {
        var type = converter.ModelClrType;

        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == type);

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name).HasConversion(converter);
            }
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: What is `TypeDomainValue`?

Comment: A class that has a Value and Description. Only the value is known in the database.

Comment: Can you please add definition and how your model builder for `Model` is set up?

Comment: If only the `Value` (presumably string since you're using `Contains` on it) is known in the database, and you're not using a FK property in your `Model` either - why is this a separate entity to begin with? This seems like you're going to be running into issues with adding new copies of untracked `TypeDomainValue` objects whenever you add and save a new `Model` to your context. Something is off about this situation and I suspect you need to rethink the design.

Comment: ModelTypeDomainValue contains some other properties that are only known in application. We keep those out of the database as the database (and the data) is owned by the customer.

Comment: if Value is a list of string   then use contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ur life easy and  Use [owned properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities) in Entity framework core.
bcs TypeDomainValue smells like that one.

- it has not its own table.
- it don't have any primary key.
- it resides in same table as Mode

so its own property.
I m not saying own properties can not have those but typically they are like them
and we use them as Value objects

Comment: While I think this is the best answer I have gone for a different approach. Give you the accept though